# Interpolate a function according to an image

Tags: image, matlab, interpolation

[image: data in image matrice][image: desired functions in matrice]

I have in this image 3 "lines".

I would like to interpulate 3 functions from the data in the picture
something like the second picture,

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First I'll assume you have a mapping of color to intensity. You really want to work with the intensity as a grayscale image.

Use a blurring function to reduce the noise in the image and help make the output continuous.

Use a vertical difference to find the line. Where the difference switches from positive to negative is the place to put your line.

Comment: the values in the "image" is real data which I'd like to keep. I've been using logic filtering or grey scale, my problem is smoothing or avereging the differences (there are a few in each vertical line for a "chunck") so it will have one line that will fit the data

Comment: @jarhead, of course you can keep the original image. I'm saying that during processing you should create a grayscale copy that represents the intensity of the data that you're mapping.

Comment: ,I've been using logic filtering and greyscale to sort the image into recognisible "chunks", my problem is smoothing or avereging the differences (there are a few in each vertical line for a "chunck") so it will have one line that will fit the data, btw, this is just a small portion of the data which is alot more noisy (unfortunatley I can not publish it....)